# How to pad a span's bottom text to align with a checkbox image?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying a pretty trivial design but still can't find a solution.

I want to make an image based design checkbox. The problem is that using this technique, I cannot use the input's `value` property to display text next to the checkbox.

So, I tried placing a `<span>` next to it, but the text is aligned to the bottom. I tried padding its bottom through various properties but with no success.

[image]

How can I pad the `<span>`'s text to vertically align with the checkbox' image? I prefer not to wrap both elements with another `<div>` which will display them as a table.

Here's a snippet of my attempt so far:

```css
.chkchk {
    display:none;
}
 
.chkchk + label {
    background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/RnoKxPS.png);
    height: 22px;
    width: 35px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.chkboxText {
    padding-bottom:10px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<input class="chkchk" type="checkbox" name="thing" value="valuable" id="thing" />
<label for="thing"></label>
<span class="chkboxText">dasdasdas</span>
```

Comment: Just add   " vertical-align: middle " in .chkchk + label

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `vertical-align: middle`. Hope it helps.

```css
.chkchk {
  display: none;
}

.chkchk+label {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/RnoKxPS.png);
  height: 22px;
  width: 35px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 0 0 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: middle
}

.chkboxText {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<input class="chkchk" type="checkbox" name="thing" value="valuable" id="thing" />
<label for="thing"></label>
<span class="chkboxText">dasdasdas</span>
```

Comment: So simple and yet I missed it. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome! But if i were you, i will not use image. I will build a checkbox with html and css. It is not too difficult

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll look into it.

Comment: Yours was the first answer, so I will.

Answer (score 3):

Add a wrapper, then add [`display:flex;`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). I also re-ordered the `html` to match the picture

```css
.wrapper{
 display:flex;
}

.chkchk {
  display: none;
}

.chkchk+label {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/RnoKxPS.png);
  height: 22px;
  width: 35px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 0 0 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.chkboxText {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="chkboxText">dasdasdas</span>
  <input class="chkchk" type="checkbox" name="thing" value="valuable" id="thing" />
  <label for="thing"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: I voted up since it's working, but I cannot accept this answer since I wrote that I do not want to add a wrapper. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Add `vertical-align: middle;` to `label`

```css
.chkchk {
    display:none;
}
 
.chkchk + label {
    background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/RnoKxPS.png);
    height: 22px;
    width: 35px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
    cursor:pointer;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.chkboxText {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<input class="chkchk" type="checkbox" name="thing" value="valuable" id="thing" />
<label for="thing"></label>
<span class="chkboxText">dasdasdas</span>
```

Comment: So simple and yet I missed it. Thanks.

Comment: Also remove `padding-bottom:10px` from `.chkboxText` it's unnecessary now.

Comment: I will. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Give `position:relative` and `bottom` to `.chkboxText`

```
.chkboxText {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 5px;//you can change this
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `vertical-align` and `padding`

```css
.chkchk {
    display:none;
}
 
.chkchk + label {
    background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/RnoKxPS.png);
    height: 22px;
    width: 35px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.chkboxText {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    
    position: relative;
}

.chkboxText:before {
  content: '';
  background: red;
  height: 1px;
  width: 50px;
  left: -50px;
  top: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<input class="chkchk" type="checkbox" name="thing" value="valuable" id="thing" />
<label for="thing"></label>
<span class="chkboxText">dasdasdas</span>
```

Comment: Thanks for this approach. Voted up.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need ?

```css
.chkchk {
    display:none;
}
 
.chkchk + label {
    background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/RnoKxPS.png);
    height: 22px;
    width: 35px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.chkboxText {
    /* padding-bottom:10px; */
    
}
.fl-bx {
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="fl-bx">
<input class="chkchk" type="checkbox" name="thing" value="valuable" id="thing" />
<label for="thing"></label>
<span class="chkboxText">dasdasdas</span>
</div>
```